# Gradle does not resolve transitive dependency inherited from parent pom

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I was converting a maven project into a gradle project,but I encountered a problem.

Here is all i have:

- project A;
- Library B from third party, and also a dependency of A
- Pom C, parent of B
- Library D, a dependency of C

So, as expected, project A should have a direct dependency B, and a transitive dependency D

it works fine in maven form that project A can access library D.But in gradle form , gradle does not treat D as a dependency of project A,it just ignores this transitive denpendency.

```
`implementation 'group:B:version'`
```

How should it declear the depencency of B in gradle to get same result as in maven

I know it is not a regular way to access D from A without declearing dependency,but I just want to archive the same goal as maven  with gradle.

Thanks for your answer ,any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `compile` instead `implementation` in a both modules (A and B) if need to access to project C from project A.

P.S. This is not recommended and **may** indicate an incorrectly designed architecture. In particular, the violation of D from SOLID.

Comment: B is a thirdparty jar in maven repository, i can't  change it's content

Comment: In this case, make sure that project B published correctly - he should be published with own pom.xml that contains own dependencies. Example: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.4.5/

Comment: Another way is to explicitly specify a dependency on project C for project A